# How to use same table in two different spark sessions sessions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If we have a big table. I created a DataFrame from it. In another spark session, I need same table. Is there any way we can use the same table to create dataframes in two different spark sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `createGlobalTempView` it will be available across Spark Sessions.

> If you want to have a temporary view that is shared among all sessions and keep alive until the Spark application terminates, you can create a global temporary view.

More information: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#global-temporary-view

Answer (score 0):

Creating a hive table
or
writing the parquet/Orc files to a shared folder?

It is more permanent but it might make sense so one spark session ending can't kill the others data.